# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'subscribe') even if sevice is spied

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm trying to test a method in my commponent. This method take two parameters **witch are not null**. I cannot call subscribe because those parameters are always un define. Please i'm pretty new in angular unit-test.

this is my `component.ts`

```
    addMatchingsToOpportunities() {
        this.formsService
          .addManualMatchingsToForms({
            code: this.formCode,
            formCodes: this.selection.selected.reduce(
              (acc, cur) => [
                ...acc,
                this.formType === FormType.Sale ? cur.purchaseCode : cur.saleCode,
              ],
              []
            ),
          })
          .subscribe({
            next: () => {
              this.redirectTo(this.formCode);
            },
          });
      }
```

and this is how my `component.spec.ts` looks like

```
fdescribe('MatchingCriteriaComponent', () => {
  let component: MatchingCriteriaComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MatchingCriteriaComponent>;
  const purchasesService = jasmine.createSpyObj<PurchasesService>(
    'purchasesService',
    [
      'getMatchingsPropositionsForPurchaseExternalGrowthForm',
      'getMatchingsPropositionsForPurchasePhysicalPersonForm',
    ]
  );
  const formsService = jasmine.createSpyObj<FormsService>('formsService', [
    'addManualMatchingsToForms',
  ]);
  const salesService = jasmine.createSpyObj<SalesService>('salesService', [
    'getMatchingsPropositionsForSaleForm',
  ]);
  const formBuilder = jasmine.createSpyObj<FormBuilder>('formBuilder', [
    'group',
  ]);
  const formCode = '000R013';
  let formCodes: string[] = [];
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
  let route : ActivatedRoute;
  

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        MatchingCriteriaComponent,
        MockComponents(GenericFilterComponent),
      ],
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([
          {path: 'details/sale/:code', component: SaleVisualizationComponent},
          {path: 'details/external-growth/:code', component: PurchasesVisualisationComponent},
          {path: 'details/physical-person/:code', component: PurchasesVisualisationComponent,}
        ]),
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        MockModule(MatButtonModule),
        MockModule(MatCardModule),
        MockModule(MatIconModule),
        MockModule(MatTableModule),
      ],
      providers: [
        { provide: PurchasesService, useValue: purchasesService },
        { provide: SalesService, useValue: salesService },
        { provide: FormsService, useValue: formsService },
        { provide: FormBuilder, useValue: formBuilder },
        { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: {params:of({formCode: formCode}) } },
      ],
    });

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MatchingCriteriaComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    route = TestBed.inject(ActivatedRoute);
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toEqual(jasmine.any(MatchingCriteriaComponent));
  });
  describe('View',() =>{
    beforeEach(()=>{
      purchasesService.getMatchingsPropositionsForPurchaseExternalGrowthForm.and.returnValue(of(MockSaleMatchingBase.saleMatchingBaseList));
      purchasesService.getMatchingsPropositionsForPurchasePhysicalPersonForm.and.returnValue(of(MockSaleMatchingBase.saleMatchingBaseList));
      salesService.getMatchingsPropositionsForSaleForm.and.returnValue(of(MockPuschaseMatchingBase.purchaseMatchingBaseList));
      
    });
    fit('Should display Matching Prposition for physical person',() =>{     
        formCodes = ['000C012'];
      formsService.addManualMatchingsToForms({code:formCode,formCodes})
      component.addMatchingsToOpportunities(); //error because parameters are undefianed
      fixture.detectChanges();
    });
});
```

I got always this error [image]

How to correctly spyOn my service ?

Answer (score 0):

Spies need to be configured to work.

When you use a spy, you just monkey-patch a function so that jasmine can spy on it, but it does not work magically out of the box.

The error happening here is that your spy is not configured to return an observable. So do it.

In your test, first line, add this :

```js
(formsService as any).addManualMatchingsToForms = jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue(null); // Put the value you need in place of null
```

Comment: Also, spies should be declared in a before each statement, to be reset automatically. Don't declare them in a describe.